# Add value from paragraf to json

Tags: javascript, json

I got a task in which I have to:

1. Make a simple text editor with options (bold, bullet and italic)
2. The editor must include options with saving and reading the file in JSON format (express library on the NODEJS side allowed) The project should be done in plain JS,
   During the second part of the task after click save. I ran into a problem, When i try to require fs i get error

> Require is not defined

Here is my code:https://github.com/neqts/printJson  and effect: https://neqts.github.io/printJson/

```js
'use strict';

const Compile = require('./compile.json');
console.log(Compile);

document.body.style.cssText = `
margin:0px;
boxing-size:border-box;
padding:0px;
background:linear-gradient(to right, #6f0000, #200122);
`;

/*create container div*/
const main = document.createElement('div');
main.classList.add('container');
document.body.appendChild(main);
main.style.cssText = `
width:100%;
height:100vh;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
text-align:center;
align-items:center;
`;

/*inside container div */
const overall = document.createElement('div');
overall.classList.add('overall');
main.appendChild(overall);
overall.style.cssText = `
width:60%;
height:300px;
background:#ffffffad;

`;

/*inside container overall */
const within = document.createElement('div');
within.classList.add('within');
overall.append(within);
within.style.cssText = `
justify-content:center;
text-align:center;
align-items:center;
height:100%;
display: inline-block;
padding-top:40px
`;

/*create buttons*/
const bold = document.createElement('button');
const lean = document.createElement('button');
const bullet = document.createElement('button');
const save = document.createElement('button');
save.classList.add('btn');
bullet.classList.add('btn');
lean.classList.add('btn');
bold.classList.add('btn');
lean.textContent = 'LEAN';
bullet.textContent = 'BULLET';
bold.textContent = 'BOLD';
save.textContent = 'SAVE';
within.appendChild(bold);
within.appendChild(lean);
within.appendChild(bullet);
within.appendChild(save);
const btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
bold.style.cssText = `
border: 3px solid black;
padding:10px;
margin:10px;
cursor:pointer;
    color: black;`;
bullet.style.cssText = `
border: 3px solid black;
padding:10px;
margin:10px;
cursor:pointer;
    color: black;`;
lean.style.cssText = `
border: 3px solid black;
padding:10px;
margin:10px;
cursor:pointer;
    color: black;`;
save.style.cssText = `
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
        color: black;`;

/*input */
const text = document.createElement('input');
within.appendChild(text);
text.id = 'myText';
text.type = 'text';
text.classList.add('text');
text.placeholder = 'Type your text here...';
text.style.cssText = `
width:80%;
background:#fff;
border:none;
margin:20px
`;
/* Info paragraf */
const Info = document.createElement('p');
within.appendChild(Info);
Info.innerHTML = `Click ENTER and start styling...`;
Info.style.cssText = `
color:gray`;

/* output text */
const outputText = document.createElement('p');
within.appendChild(outputText);
outputText.classList = 'outputText';
outputText.style.cssText = `
width:100%;
height:30px;`;

/* ENTER function */
const show = function () {
  let paragraf = document.getElementById('myText').value;
  outputText.innerText = paragraf;
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    show();
  }
});
let li;
let ul;

const paragraChangePoint = function () {
  ul = document.createElement('ul');
  li = document.createElement('li');
  within.appendChild(ul);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  outputText.style.display = 'none';
  li.innerText = outputText.innerText;
};

const paragrafChangeBold = function () {
  outputText.style.fontWeight = '700';
  li.style.fontWeight = '700';
};
const paragrafChangeLean = function () {
  outputText.style.fontStyle = 'Italic';
  li.style.fontStyle = 'Italic';
};

   
const obj = {
  table: [],
};

const paragrafSave = function () {
  obj.table.push({ text: outputText });
  const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback);
};

bullet.addEventListener('click', paragraChangePoint);
lean.addEventListener('click', paragrafChangeLean);
bold.addEventListener('click', paragrafChangeBold);
save.addEventListener('click', paragrafSave);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Recruitment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're doing it on the browser. `require` doesn't work on the browser, so it's throwing the error. What you have to do, is include it in a `script` tag, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Can u tak a look I tried to do it like u said but still get the error here is updated code https://github.com/neqts/printJson and here is live project https://neqts.github.io/printJson/

Comment: You're still trying to use `require`. I told you, `require` doesn't work. There's a difference between `node.js` and `javascript`.